# Problema com subdomínio Apache2

Tags: linux, apache, subdomínio

Preciso configurar o apache do Linux Debian para meu subdomínio .
Já reiniciei o server Apache. O subdomínio está configurado a IP do servidor 
registro tipo A.

```
Arquivo: /etc/apache2/sites-available/lolo.conf
diretorio: projetos ( estão todos os arquivos de subdominio)
<VirtualHost *>
ServerAdmin webmaster@meudominio.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/projetos
ServerName projetos.meudominio.com
ServerAlias *.projetos.meudominio.com
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/projetos-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

O domínio funciona perfeitamente. Não sei q fazer.

Comment: A config aparentemente está correta. Pode executar o comando `apache2ctl configtest` e postar o resultado, por favor?

Comment: Bruno Coimbra - desculpe a demora em responder e obrigado pela preocupação!
o Servidor já está fora do ar.
Obrigado msm assim, valeu!